# How to use group_concat with the sum of quantity based on price?

Tags: mysql, sql, eloquent

This is my table which store id with its qty and price. I would like to sum qty based on price. Sometimes the qty might be show 0 if qty is negative value. Thus, i will not show the price of qty fall in 0 value when group by price.

```
id | id_item | qty | price
1    1         10    1.00
2    1         15    2.00
3    1         10    1.00
4    2         5     2.00
5    2         5     2.50
6    3         10    1.00
7    3         10    1.00
8    3         5     1.00
```

This is what i have tried.

```
Select id_item, price, sum(qty) as total from sales group by id_item, price having total !=0;

Result
id_item | qty | price
1         20    1.00
1         15    2.00
2         5     2.00
2         5     2.50
3         10    1.00
```

Expected result with concat

```
id_item | qty     | price
1         20,15     1.00,2.00
2         5,5       2.00.2.50
3         10        1.00
```

How can i achieve the result as shown？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need two levels of aggregation:

```
select id_item, group_concat(total order by price) as quantities,
       group_concat(price order by price) as prices
from (Select id_item, price, sum(qty) as total
      from sales
      group by id_item, price
      having total <> 0
     ) s
group by id_item;
```